# Scaml syntax highlighting on Emacs

Tags: scala, emacs, syntax-highlighting, scalate

How can I get Scaml (Scalate) syntax highlighting on Emacs?
Already using Scala-mode.

Comment: same question about SSP (`.ssp`) but I guess the answers would be similar for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of anyone implementing a scaml syntax highlighting for emacs.  BUT it seems like some good folks did implement [haml syntax highlighting](https://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/da9ed66cd49d8c9fc63420378d159997934ac7ea/extra/haml-mode.el).  Since HAML and SCAML are so similar, you might get a way with just using that or at least it could give you a good start for implementing a SCAML syntax highlighter.